# Make a d3 div resizable by drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, d3.js

***Question:***

I have implemented a version of a `d3.js` tree found [here](https://gist.github.com/robschmuecker/7880033).

Now, in my case, the tree doesn't take the whole screen, but it is conveniently put into a `div`, since it is just a part of a dash-board I've created.

Here is the css of the `div` where the tree is put:

```
#tree-container {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-color: #b0c4de;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    top:2px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

What I want to do is: when the user clicks on the boarder of the `div` - to be able to resize it by dragging the pointer of the mouse (when clicked, of course).

---

***What I've tried so far?***

So far, I've tried like shown on the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17855401/how-do-i-make-a-div-width-draggable):

```
$('#tree-container').resizable({
    handles: 'n,w,s,e',
    minWidth: 200,
    maxWidth: 400
});
```

But, this doesn't work. In fact - it raises an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

When I try like this:

```
$('#tree-container').resize({
        handles: 'n,w,s,e',
        minWidth: 200,
        maxWidth: 400
    });
```

it doesn't raise an error, but it still doesn't work.

This doesn't work as well:

```
$('#tree-container').resize({
        handles: 'n,w,s,e'
    });
```

Any ideas of how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Do you include jQuery-UI instead of just jQuery?

Comment: I includ jQuery in the head of my html like this: `<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>`

Comment: You also need to include [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/)

Comment: This seems to have a lot of files. What do I need more precisely to include?

Comment: You'll need "UI Core" and from "Interactions" you'll need "Resizable". Like [this](http://jqueryui.com/download/#!version=1.11.1&components=1111001000000000000000000000000000000).

Comment: It's definitely a start, but I still can't make it work. Any chance  you could provide a code example?

Comment: Well, there are plenty code examples [here](http://jqueryui.com/resizable/). I've never used it myself so far.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can achieve this with d3 alone. No need for jQuery UI.

You need to create an absolutely positioned div inside the resizable div, and add a drag behavior to it.

[Here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/meetamit/e38bLdjk/1/). Drag the orange rectangle to resize.

Here's the relevant code:

```
var resizable = d3.select('#resizable');
var resizer = resizable.select('.resizer');

var dragResize = d3.behavior.drag()
    .on('drag', function() {
        // Determine resizer position relative to resizable (parent)
        x = d3.mouse(this.parentNode)[0];

        // Avoid negative or really small widths
        x = Math.max(50, x);

        resizable.style('width', x + 'px');
    })

resizer.call(dragResize);
```

Comment: Although slightly modified, this solved my problem! Tnx a lot for your answer!