# How can I resize a left side div on its right side only, and it's neighboring right side div, on its left side only, using jqueryui?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have two divs side by side. I'm using jquery ui to make them resizable. However, I'm having a problem because I'm trying to use the '`alsoResize`' property to resize the div next to it.

If I resize the right side of my left div, then the left side of my right div should also resize accordingly.

Using '`alsoResize`' alongside '`handles`' doesnt work, and when I resize the right side of my left div, the right side of my right div also get resized.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish what I need to do?

jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/hh3ue3op/5/

Comment: Yes, a fiddle, or at the minimum, include your code here

Comment: @Ted sorry updated post with jsfiddle

Comment: I offer [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8r8qhoq0/) for consideration... not sure if that's the desired effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the 'handles' parameter for jQuery UIs .resizable() function. http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/

Here's a good example taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17856082/2466782):

```
$( ".selector" ).resizable({ handles: "n, e, s, w" });
```

[Updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QkZL8/15/)

Comment: I'm already using handles, problem is that 'alsoResize' apparently overrides handles.

Comment: the problem with this solution is my divs are not parent > child, and if I were to make it so then the child would simply overlap the parent. I need both divs, side by side, resize according to one another. However because they both display content, one cannot overlap the other.

Comment: I see. In that case, this answer seems to be what you're looking for. You'll have to modify the code a bit, but it appears to be doing what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369045/jquery-ui-resizable-alsoresize-reverse

Comment: I looked into that answer, if you notice that it works fine north and south direction, however the resizing east and west does the opposite of what I need. I was messing with it to try to achieve what I need but so far havent figured it out

Comment: Thanks! I guess that will work, wish I'd found something elegant for both but I'll just add to this for the up down behavior as well. Thanks for finding it!

Comment: ugh its not working for me because my divs have position:absolute, got any suggestions to fix that? It seems to be taking width away from the right hand side of the right div.

Comment: Don't position your divs that are being resized. Instead, wrap them in a container div and absolutely position the container.