# Resize two halves of a browser screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to make that **hovering the mouse over the boundary between two elements** (here on the vertical line which separates the blue and red) 
makes it possible to resize the width of each element?

I'm looking for the behaviour of https://stackedit.io/editor

Is this possible directly with `<textarea>` resizing possibilities ?

```css
* { margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; }
textarea { background-color: red; width: 50%; position: absolute; top:0; left:0; height: 100%; }
#separator { cursor: ew-resize; position: absolute; top:0; width:1%; left:50%; height: 100%; }
#right { background-color: blue; width: 49%;  position: absolute; top:0; right:0; height: 100%;}
```

```html
<textarea>hello</textarea>
<div id="separator"></div>
<div id="right">yo</div>
```

Comment: Answered here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17855401/how-do-i-make-a-div-width-draggable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17855401/how-do-i-make-a-div-width-draggable)

Comment: Maybe not have position absolute. Position:absolute; **MEANS** that the position is **absolute** and cannot and will not be moved no matter what. Their position is locked to the coordinates

Comment: @Call_Back_Function isn't it possible easily without jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Sort of like this:

```css
* { margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; }
html,body { height: 100% }
textarea { background-color: red; width: 50%; height: 100%; resize: horizontal; min-width: 1px; max-width: 99%; float: left; }
div { background-color: blue; height: 100%}
textarea:active {width: 1px;}
```

```html
<textarea>hello</textarea>
<div>yo</div>
```

Note that the textarea:active style is necessary because of an [issue with chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=94583) that won't allow an element to be resized less than it's initial width.  It's a bad hack to work around it until chrome fixes it.

Comment: Nice @RobertMcKee, but how to be able to resize when hovering *anywhere* on the vertical line? Currently it only works when hovering the bottom of the page...

Comment: Well for that you'd need something a bit more complicated, likely needing some javascript and another element to serve as the divider.

Comment: In the original question, I had a divider #separator, do you think it could be possible to reuse that, and to have this behaviour, without javascript?

Comment: Interesting that your original question has a divider, because I copied your question to form mine, and it didn't have it.  I however can not think of a way to reuse it without using javascript off the top of my head.